# Find and Draw $\ S=f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$ where $\ f(x,y)=y(x-y)\ $

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\ f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ be given by $\ f(x,y)=y(x-y)\ $. Find and draw the pre-imiage $\ S=f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$.

I always try to include a response in my questions, but I am unsure how to attempt this question. I don't quite understand how to start this question. Is there some intuition/method that I can use?

Comment: What do you get when you apply the definition of a preimage and simplify?

Comment: I am unsure. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all points $(x,y)$ satisfying $y(x-y)\geq 0$. There are two cases to analyse:

1) $y\geq 0$ and $x-y\geq 0$ : These inequalities describe the region bellow the graphic of $y=x$ such that $y\geq 0$.
 2) $y\leq 0$ and $x-y\leq 0$ : These inequalities describe the region above the graphic of $y=x$ such that $y\leq 0$.

So the region described is the one between the lines $y=x$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Just a quick question. How did you know to consider the second case? This does not seem intuitive to me.

Comment: @Bell It's a general rule that for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $a \cdot b \geqslant 0 \iff (a \geqslant 0 \text{ and } b \geqslant 0) \text{ or } (a \leqslant 0 \text{ and } b \leqslant 0)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!